# Implement push notifications in Flutter

Tags: flutter, push-notification

How to implement notification system like WhatsApp even when the app is closed. I want to get the notifications whenever the device is connected with the internet again

Please help me with the problem using firebase push notifications solution

Comment: Try this link:
https://medium.com/comerge/implementing-push-notifications-in-flutter-apps-aef98451e8f1

Answer (score 0):

Check out the FlutterFire documentation : https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications